How to retrieve the Signature hash algorithm friendly name using c# BouncyCastle 2.4.0?
I am trying to sign a file with the private key and the hash algorithm read from a certificate and I cannot find a way to do it programmatically:
public byte[] SignFile(string filePath, X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    using var rsaPrivateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    using var fileStream = this.fileSystem.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var hashAlgorithmFromTheCertificate = HashAlgorithmName.SHA1; // <== How to get this from the certificate instead of hard-coding it?
    return rsaPrivateKey!.SignData(fileStream, hashAlgorithmFromTheCertificate, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
} 

I have seen the Reflection-based solution here:
How to retrieve the Signature hash algorithm friendly name using c# cryptography?
Is there a clean way to do it or are we stuck with Reflection?
I am using:
BouncyCastle.Cryptography Version="2.4.0"
Thanks in advance
I have tried to use:
var algoName = HashAlgorithmName.FromOid(certificate.SignatureAlgorithm.Value!);
But it throws:
The specified OID (XXXXXXXXXXXX) does not represent a known hash algorithm

Did you check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36280288/2794280?

Yes. It's the link I pasted above. Any better idea?

The certificate only contains the signature algorithm, so you need a mapping from the signature algorithm to the hash algorithm. If you do not want to use reflections, you can create a dictionary yourself (which contains the values of the BouncyCastle mapping).

@Topaco: Can you provide some code? Where do I get these "BouncyCastle mappings"?

Create the mapping as described in the linked answer and output the result. Use a dictionary with these values and use it to determine the HashAlgorithmName value required in the SignData() method. See online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zjz4aR
